# How can I hear my iPhone's audio while recording its screen on my mac using QuickTime Player?

Tags: iphone, audio, screen-capture, quicktime

I know how to record my iPhone's screen on my mac using QuickTime Player (while the phone and mac are connected via lightning cable), but when I do that, my phone's sound goes off. I even installed Apowersoft's virtual soundcard and chose the input microphone to be Apowersoft_AudioDevice on QuickTime Player's movie recording, but my phone is still mute.

Is there a way I can hear my phone's audio while recording the video on my mac?

Comment: Have you considered the iPhone's built-in screen record?
Alternatively, if sound quality isn't important, you could record the phone's screen and the computer's microphone and then airplay your iPhone's sound to a bluetooth speaker that is near your computer?

Comment: @JBallin I don't really want to record my phone's screen. I'm trying to find a way to mirror my phone's screen on my mac and stream video. I can't use AirPlay, because my macbook is actually connected to the hotspot from my phone, and I don't have wifi (airplay needs the devices to be connected to the same wifi).

Comment: Are you sure you couldn’t airplay to a Bluetooth device, such as AirPods (doesn’t require WiFi)?

Comment: @JBallin You mean airplaying the audio only? I haven't tried. I'll try to stream the audio from a separate device while mirroring the screen on my mac using movie recording feature of QuickTime Player to see if it works.

Comment: Right, just the audio. Would have to be on an audio only device I think (as opposed to an Apple TV for example). Worth a shot. Haha I love how complicated this has become.

Comment: @JBallin I tried and it didn't work. The sound still goes off once I change the source device to my iPhone on QuickTime Player's movie recording. This is so annoying. Is there really no way I can stream my phone on my laptop with the audio?!!

Comment: hmm so I just tried it with youtube and it worked. I have camera set to iPhone, microphone set to internal, and I have my iPhone airplaying to my bt headphones.